why js only displays the second element of json?
I want to display all elements of json. but it only displays the second element. please help.
A pkl file is:
[('2003@Bush.txt', [[('That', 'DT'), ('request', 'NN'), ('will', 'MD'), ('present', 'VB'), ('President', 'NNP'), ('Bush', 'NNP'), ('with', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('quandary', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]...

server side:
import pickle from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, request, jsonify import re

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the pickled data with open('data/indexed_data.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    indexed_data = pickle.load(file)
    print("Indexed Data:", indexed_data)
    print("Type of indexed_data:", type(indexed_data))  # Debug print
    print("Length of indexed_data:", len(indexed_data))  # Debug print

@app.route('/') def index():
    return send_from_directory('web_root', 'index.html')

@app.route('/search') def search():
    query = request.args.get('query')

    if not query:
        return jsonify([])  # Return an empty list if query is empty

    # Normalize the query by removing leading and trailing spaces and converting to lowercase
    query = query.strip().lower()

    # Perform search based on the provided query
    results = perform_search(query)

    return jsonify(results)


def perform_search(query):
    # Initialize an empty list to store search results
    search_results = []

    # Split the query into individual words
    keywords = query.lower().split()

    # Generate a regex pattern for matching any single word after "present president"
    query_regex = re.sub(r'#', r'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', query)

    # Iterate through each tuple in the indexed data list
    for filename, sentences in indexed_data:
        # Iterate through each sentence in the sentences list
        for sentence in sentences:
            # Extract words from the sentence and convert them to lowercase
            sentence_words = [word.lower() for word, _ in sentence]
            # Convert the sentence to a string for regex matching
            sentence_str = ' '.join(sentence_words)

            # Check if the regex pattern matches the sentence
            match = re.search(query_regex, sentence_str)
            if match:
                # Extract the matched pattern
                matched_pattern = match.group(0)
                # If there is a match, add the filename, matched pattern, and sentence to search results
                search_results.append((filename, matched_pattern, sentence_str))
    #print(search_results) #this is ok, it outputs filename, matched_pattern and sentence_str
    return search_results

js code is:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const searchForm = document.getElementById('searchForm');
    const queryInput = document.getElementById('queryInput');
    const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');

    searchForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
        const query = queryInput.value.trim(); // Get the search query
        const encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query); // Encode the query
        // Perform search
        if (query !== '') {
            search(encodedQuery);
        } else {
            resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Please enter a search query.</p>';
        }
    });

    function search(query) {
        // Send search query to backend
        fetch(`/search?query=${query}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                displayResults(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>An error occurred while performing the search.</p>';
            });
    }

  function displayResults(results) {
    // Clear previous results
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = '';

    // Display new results
    if (results.length > 0) {
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        results.forEach(result => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            // Create a string containing all three elements separated by a separator
            const resultString = `${result[0]} (${result[1]}): ${result[2]}`;
            li.textContent = resultString;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        });
        resultsDiv.appendChild(ul);
    } else {
        resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>No results found.</p>';
    }
}


});

But it only always outputs the second element, matched_pattern.
i want to display all the elements in json, how?

Please narrow down the part where the error happens and create a minimal reproducible example.

Figure out whether that's a problem in your backend code or frontend code and only focus on that.

On the server, add console.log(results) right after results = perform_search(query) and add console.log(displayResults) as the first line of displayResults and see if you return from the server the same as you expect on the client. If the data looks as expected on the client, the problem is in your displayResults. Use console.log to verify what result is equal to in your forEach.
